# More logic to the script

Tags: powershell, citrix

I have this that I've been working on today but I think there is a better way. Thanks for the help. The goal is to clean up Citrix for users. Sometimes they get a bad .ica file.

```
Stop-Process -processname Receiver
sleep 60
Remove-Item $env:LOCALAPPDATA\temp\*.ica
Remove-Item $env:LOCALAPPDATA\temp\2\CTXReceiverLogs -Recurse
Remove-Item $env:LOCALAPPDATA\temp\2 -Recurse
Remove-Item $env:LOCALAPPDATA\temp\3\CTXReceiverLogs -Recurse
Remove-Item $env:LOCALAPPDATA\temp\3 -Recurse
Remove-Item $env:LOCALAPPDATA\temp\4\CTXReceiverLogs -Recurse
Remove-Item $env:LOCALAPPDATA\temp\4 -Recurse
Remove-Item $env:LOCALAPPDATA\temp\CTXReceiverLogs\1\*.etl
Remove-Item $env:LOCALAPPDATA\temp\CTXReceiverLogs\1\ -Recurse
Remove-Item $env:LOCALAPPDATA\temp\CTXReceiverLogs\ -Recurse
Remove-Item $env:LOCALAPPDATA\temp\CitrixLogs -Recurse
Remove-Item $env:LOCALAPPDATA\temp\*.tmp -Recurse
```

Comment: ``Remove-Item $env:LOCALAPPDATA\temp -recurse -force``?

Comment: Not sure what your asking me there, I dont want to delete everything in the temp folder. Has to be selective

Comment: well, you could at least slim those down to like temp\2 -recurse temp3\-recurse temp4\ -recurse ctxreceiverlogs -recurse

Comment: It looks like you're wanting to remove any `CTXReceiverLogs`, *and* that folder's _parent directory_ as well.  Is this correct?  In addition to `CitrixLogs`, and all `.ica` and `.tmp` files.  By the way, a large number of the `.tmp` removals will almost certainly result in file access errors.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
get-childitem -recurse -include CTXReceiverLogs*, *.ica, *.etl, *.tmp |   remove-item -recurse -force
```

Of course you've to adapt the `include` parameters to your needs.